# Spring cloud stream partitionKeyExpression SpEL

Tags: spring-el, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-cloud-stream-kafka to write a small stress test which produces a lot of events and sends them to a specific Kafka topic.

The topic has 6 partitions and I'd like to use a user ID as a partitioning key. However, the user ID is not always present, so I'd like the logic to be like this: Partition by user ID if it exists, otherwise send to a random partition.

Is there a way to use the

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression
```

property to achieve wanted behavior?

P.S. I was able to create an extractor class that does that, but I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve that with Spel.

Thanks, 
Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Elvis Operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-elvis) ?

Something like

```
 payload.userId ?: Math.random() * 6
```

?

Comment: Nope, this does not work because the userId does not exist as a property in a payload json. I think that this would work if I the event I get always contain the property userId, but sometimes the property is _null_. Something like _userId: null_.

Comment: If it's is json you can use #jsonpath in your elvis expression.

Comment: Yes, that's working! Thanks! For completeness, I'll just add that you need to configure you jsonPath, setting the option `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL`, otherwise will throw an error if the property does not exist!